# Switching power supply has high ripple voltage no matter how many capacitors are added

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, texas-instruments, ripple

I'm designing a board that uses a Texas Instruments TLV62569DBVR [(datasheet here)](https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1809251629_Texas-Instruments-TLV62569DBVR_C141836.pdf) to convert 5V input from a USB power supply to 3.3 volts to be used to power an ESP32-WROOM-32D-N4. I am having lots of issues with rippling voltage and no matter how many filter capacitors I add, the issue persists.

My Current PCB layout is as follows:
[image: Current PCB layout. Traces have net labels if you zoom in.]
[image: bottom side carries 5V and 3V]

All capacitors are: CL21A226MAQNNNE. Have also tried the 10 uF version of this capacitor with the same results

L1: [SMMS0530-2R2M](https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2108131730_SXN-Shun-Xiang-Nuo-Elec-SMMS0530-2R2M_C181723.pdf)

R16: 100K ohms

R17: 400K ohms

R20: 50K ohms

U1: TLV62569DBVR

I suspect it is either because the sense trace is way too big (Net FB) or that it is getting interference from the inductor. Any input is welcome!

[image: rippling voltage]

Comment: Could you please show how you probed the output voltage? Should have been like [this](https://www.cui.com/products/image/getimage/73400?typecode=m).

Comment: Also please zoom in; 5ms/div is uselessly far out and it's impossible to tell what frequency band the ripple is in.

Comment: Please add a schematic of your circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *no matter how many filter capacitors I add, the issue persists.*

This sort of problem usually comes down to your oscilloscope probes picking up magnetically induced voltages from the switching currents. Try shorting your probe out to the ground wire crocodile clip and see what sort of signal you get in the vicinity of your circuit board.

Without making any electrical connection you will probably see the same level of ripple voltage (induced by the changing magnetic field).

There are recommended ways to probe these types of circuit and those ways definitely **do not** include using a crocodile clip ground lead.

Comment: The issue ended up being that port 2 on my oscilloscope has some kind of interference internally. I switched to port one of the oscilloscope and presto. No problem. 

To quote sherlock holms:
When you have eliminated all that is possible, then whatever remains however improbable, must be the truth.

Thanks for your help.